# Why additional input series damping for AD797

Tags: operational-amplifier

In [AD797's datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD797.pdf), section "THE NONINVERTING CONFIGURATION", it states that because of the low \$ r_{BB} \$, that the AD797 needs additional input series damping. Shown as below:

[image]

Without the two resistors in the circuit above, it can also used as a voltage follower.
But the document recommends R1 because "very little damping of input and output reactive interactions" if we connect the output directly to the inverting input. I can't understand this well. How does the lack of damping of input and output reactive interactions degrade the stability?

Comment: Looks like a base stopper resistor.

Comment: Hmm, Not sure what you are asking about.  From the little I read, they where talking about R2.  Some series R on the input.  (see figure 16.)  (R1 may be there to limit the current  into the inverting input.  A few pF and 100 ohms shouldn't be too much of a problem.)

Comment: Yes, i mean the resistor R1, R2 only makes the input balanced.  So, R1 is noly used to limit the current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that to excite a resonant mode you have to put energy into that node at the right frequency.  What they are saying is that for low noise reasons they made the parasitic resistance on the order of 6 Ohms. The lower that either R or C is in the RC time constant the higher the frequency that is passed.  So what they are saying is that putting a 100 Ohm resistor in there will take the edges off just enough that the risk of the device ringing is greatly reduced.  Of course there are considerations for noise and bandwidth so this value is as small as possible while still doing little to add to noise.

Comment: Does this kind of instability have some relations with the classical 'feedback' theory? Because the addition of R1 will add additional phase shift, so it also recommends to parallel one capacitor with R1. So i think adding of R1 just like the 'RLC' circuit analysis. It's not the same problem with 'feedback' analysis.

Comment: It's simply a matter of scale.  With low Rbb and low stray C the pole is at a very high frequency. Adding in 100 Ohms moves it down by ~ 1 -2 orders of magnitude, within the control range of the op-amp. The "speed-up" capacitor puts in a pole that is another 2 orders of magnitude lower down (20 pf vs. > 1 pF on chip)